# creating a new dataframe from the unique values of another dataframe column

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Question may be a duplicate one but they are not as simple as this,
I have a dataframe (df) as:

```
city | address |. . .
hyd     .
hyd     . 
sec     . 
los
los
miy
```

.
.
.

I have tried my luck as this:

```
df1['unique']=df.city.unique()
```

How may I achieve a new dataframe
`df1` having unique city names of `df['city']` as

```
city
hyd
sec
miy
.
.
```

Comment: try this, `df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.city.unique(), columns=['unique'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.city.dropna().unique(), columns=['unique'])
```

O/P:

```
  unique
0    hyd
1    sec
2    los
3    miy
```

If you want it as Series,

```
s = pd.Series(df.city.dropna()unique(), name= 'series')

0    hyd
1    sec
2    los
3    miy
Name: series, dtype: object
```

Comment: Use `dropna()`, added to the solution.